# Python webbrowser search with default search engine

Tags: python, browser, python-webbrowser

Trying to determine how I would use pythons `webbrowser` library to search a string on the USERS set search engine.

My current line is

```
wb.open_new(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={string}")
```

However that only searches the string in google.

If you try just entering the string. The browser is trying to resolve the string. Not searching in the default search engine.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. `webbrowser` is a simple interface to open *a URL* in *a browser*. These browsers may not have any notion of a built-in search engine or such. You'd need to address a specific browser you know has this feature specifically using its own API in some way.